# How do you handle "#NUM!" in a SharePoint calculated field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date-time

When you use `DATEDIF` in a SharePoint Calculated field and the result is negative the function returns `#NUM!` how can I detect that value with an `IF` to branch around it?

```
=IF(DATEDIF(NOW(),[Proposal Status Date],"d")="#NUM!",1,2)
```

Ultimately, overdue "Proposals" return a negative value which isn't cool with `DATEDIF`.

Thanks! I hope this makes sense.

Guess I could just compare the dates first (?) -- just asking...

Comment: Such a great question. Stack overflow gave me a badge... Weee... No one voted for it though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ISERROR()` function.

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(NOW(),[Proposal Status Date],"d")),1,2)
```

- **ISERR**: Value refers to any error value except #N/A.
- **ISERROR**: Value refers to any error value (#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!).
- **ISNA**: Value refers to the #N/A (value not available) error value.

[IS functions](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IS-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087)

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolve by using this formula :

**=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(NOW(),[Proposal Status Date],"d")), -DATEDIF(NOW(),[Proposal Status Date],"d"))**